# javascript alert message russian text

Tags: javascript

how do i give  a alert message in russian text?

these chars means name = & #1048;& #1084;& #1103;
if you put them in normal html , it shows Имя

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qn84W/2/show/light/

Just alert the literal russian text? Assuming you serve the page as UTF-8.

Comment: thanks for your reply when i save the page as html , it shows me javascript alert with russian text; But if i save the same file as php file it gives some garbage characters as alert.. saving html as php shouldnt give this problem.. any idea why this happening?

Comment: looks like cache problem on local server.. working fine on online server  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use arbitrary Unicode characters in Javascript string literals.

You can also use hexadecimal escape codes: `"\u0418..."` (You'll need to convert to hex)